# Trouble understanding where to make API Calls in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I come from an Angular world where we separate out components, services, and templates rather than using Next.js `actions` and normally I do not need to consider a `server` vs `client` component which I believe is where my confusion comes from.

I am implementing a 3rd party API which requires navigating the User to a 3rd party window/page to grant my application permission to access their information using this 3rd party API.  Upon the user granting access, the user is then redirected by to my application with a key in the `queryParams` called `code`.

As such, I have an `action.ts` which contains a function that attempts to use this `code` moving forward, which requires me to get that code from the URL, now that I have been granted access:

```
/**
 * @param code Auth Token received after a User has given us access to their info
 */
export async function getUserProfileFrom3rdPartyAPI(code: string): Promise<any> {

  const headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + btoa(`${code}`),
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  }
  try {
    const response = await fetch(https://www.example.com/123', {
      headers: headers
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    if (data) {
      return data;
    }
  } catch (e) { console.error(e); }
}
```

I then have a component that is relying on a code to be passed into its' `props` which would then, in turn, call the above action to display the results:

```
'use client'

import { OUATH_URI } from "@/app/lib/actions";
import profile from "@/app/ui/profile";
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'

export default function Page() {
  let data;

  const params = useSearchParams();
  let code = params.get('code');
  
  return (
    <>
      <p>Welcome to profile page <a href="/">Back to dashboard</a></p>
      <button><a target="_blank" href={OUATH_URI}>I want to grant access to my profile information</a></button>
      <hr />
      <Profile code={code} />
    </>
  )
}
```

And finally, the Profile component that wants to combine all this logic into a clean UI (but at the moment I am just trying to get data into a state where I actually can get it into the UI..):

```
import { getUserProfileFrom3rdPartyAPI} from "../lib/actions";

export default async function Profile({ code }: { code: string | null }) {
  if (!code) return;
  let data;

  console.log(code);
  await getUserProfileFrom3rdPartyAPI(code).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    data = response;
  });

  return (
    <code>{data}</code>
  )
}
```

I continue to get an error:

`Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding 'use client' to a module that was originally written for the server.`

Which I understand in theory, but I think I must be missing something fundamentally about how to structure my application properly in this non-angular framework and I am asking what I should change or where I can learn how to better understand my issue. I am trying to use `useSearchParams()` to get those param values, however, I do not think I am using it in the proper way, given this error.